# How to create and use integer array with while loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make integer array for **last_foto** and add to the loop. I tried this code:

```
var last_foto = [];

function img()
{
    for(var i=1; i<9; i++)
    {
         var foto_rand = Math.floor(3*Math.random()+i*3);
         $("#foto-"+ i).html('<img style="position: relative;" height="100%" src="slides/'+ foto_rand +'.jpg" />');
         var last_foto[i] = foto_rand;
    }
}

function rimg()
{
    var rand = Math.floor(8*Math.random()+1);
    var foto_rand = Math.floor(3*Math.random()+3*rand);
    while(last_foto[rand] == foto_rand) var foto_rand = Math.floor(3*Math.random()+3*rand);
    $("#foto-"+ rand).fadeOut(2000, function() {
         $("#foto-"+ rand).html('<img style="position: relative;" height="100%" src="slides/'+ foto_rand +'.jpg" />');
    });
    $("#foto-"+ rand).fadeIn(2000);
    var last_foto[rand] = foto_rand;
}
```

But after I add:

```
var last_foto = [];

var last_foto[i] = foto_rand;

while(last_foto[rand] == foto_rand) var foto_rand = Math.floor(3*Math.random()+3*rand);

var last_foto[rand] = foto_rand;
```

All JavaScript code stop working.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: I don't know I using Notepad++ and host for testing.

Comment: Create a fiddle on www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Z6Tz5/

Comment: rimg() looks like really nasty code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var last_foto[i] = foto_rand;
```

This isn't valid. And because you've already initialized the array you don't need to use the `var` keyword.

In both your `img()` and `rimg()` functions.

Also, you seem to be redeclaring a lot of your variables. Once a variable is declared it doesn't need to be redeclared unless you're in a different scope and want to overwrite the global with a local of the same name (although I'd recommend against it for readability)

Comment: @cgatian - yeah agreed, I don't think it would solve all the problems the OP has.

Answer (score 0):

use the built in `Array.push(item)` and `Array.pop()` in the loop and you can skip the counter